# RStudio Git Version Control keeps adding random commits

Tags: r, git, github, rstudio

I'm very new to GitHub and am not super experienced in R yet, and I've created a GitHub repository for a class project and it was all going well, but commits like these keep popping up in my Git pane in RStudio, and I have no idea where they are coming from. Attached is a screenshot of what they look like.

[image]

I've tried everything ChatGPT has told me to do but I'm just not experienced enough to figure out why even that won't solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

those are not really commits but tracked changes in your git-repo. That is exactly what `git` is supposed to do. It is up to you now to decide what you want to do with these changes (commit, revert, ignore, ...).

You can fix this by changing the `.gitignore`-file. You can simply copy the contents from here which is optimized for `R`: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/R.gitignore

Or you can add this to fix the problems from your screenshot:

```
# RStudio files
.Rproj.user/
```